# Nested SQL statement or view? What would be ideal?

Tags: java, sql, view, nested

I'm trying to create a fitting SQL query for my Java discussion board. My program basically needs the username, messagetext, created (which is the date of creation) to display in the GUI via a PreparedStatement.

The tables look like this (I left out some columns):

table message:

messageid, projectid, employeeid, messagetext, created

table employee:

employeeid, username

No I've tried this which works fine except that I need the username and not the employeeid:

```
SELECT messageid, projectid, employeeid, messagetext, created, updated 
FROM message
WHERE projectid = 4
```

I know I can get the right usernames by doing this:

```
SELECT username
FROM employee
INNER JOIN message
ON employee.employeeid=message.employeeid
```

But how do I fit the two together into one statement? Because my JAVA Code creates a Message Object with the data it gets from the statement:

```
    String query="SELECT messageid, projectid, employeeid, messagetext, createdFROM message WHERE projectid= ?";

    stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

    stmt.setInt(1, id);

    stmt.executeQuery();

    rs = stmt.getResultSet();

    while(rs.next()) {

        int messageid = rs.getInt("messageid");
        int projectid = rs.getInt("projectid");
        int employeeid = rs.getInt("employeeid");

        String messagetext = rs.messagetext ("messagetext ");
        String created = rs.getString("created");

        ObjMessage oMsg = new ObjMessage (messageid, projectid, employeeid, messagetext, created); 

        AllMessages.add(oMsg);
    }
```

Do I have to rework my object creation process to acceept two resultstatements? Or is there a better way?

Disclaimer: I reworked some of the JAVA variables to be in English so there might be some errors there...

Comment: Use the `outer join` to get the employee's username in the first select statement and pass it to the `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.username, m.messageid, m.projectid, m.employeeid, m.messagetext, m.created, m.updated 
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN message m
ON e.employeeid=m.employeeid
```

Comment: This works perfectly I just added the WHERE projectid = ? at the end again.